# Body wrap not going to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a page wrap that is meant to give everything under my navbar a background color. However, whenever the page goes past the scroll point the background-color stops and the color goes back to white.

This is the wrap...

```
.draftPageWrap {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #303030;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The html:

The starting tag is right under the navbar and the closing tag is right above the closing `</body>` tag.

I have tried making this absolute and it works in a way, but it doesn't. It covers up my nav bar.

I have this in my css file as well :

```
html ,body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I can't believe I'm asking this question, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you post a working example of the problem?

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.net example to demonstrate your issue. Thanks.

Comment: My jsfiddle isn't replicating the issue.

Comment: If `.draftPageWrap` is a `div` (or has `display:block`), then `min-height: 100%;` should be enough. Try removing `position`, `bottom` etc properties.